# How to replace the entries of a matrix by another matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a two matrix mm and nn. Matrix mm is of dimension 8 cross 8 and nn is of dimensions 4 cross 4. I want to replace the first four rows and columns in mm by nn. How to do this?

```
mm = ConstantArray[q, {8, 8}]
nn = ConstantArray[r, {4, 4}]
```

Comment: Try `mm[[;; 4, ;; 4]] = nn`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Table` and make any changes you like

```
Table[mm[[j, k]] = nn[[j, k]], {j, 4}, {k, 4}]
```

> {{r,r,r,r,q,q,q,q},{r,r,r,r,q,q,q,q},{r,r,r,r,q,q,q,q},{r,r,r,r,q,q,q,q},{q,q,q,q,q,q,q,q},{q,q,q,q,q,q,q,q},{q,q,q,q,q,q,q,q},{q,q,q,q,q,q,q,q}}

Comment: `Do` makes more sense here than `Table`.